# Обработка данных json

Tags: php, json, include

Здравствуйте. Возникла такая проблема.

```
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "main");
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");

if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT DISTINCT manufacturer FROM oc_1auto order by 1;")) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $myArray[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($myArray);
} 

$result->close();
```

Этот код отрабатывает хорошо, данные выводятся на стороне клиента.

Я хочу сделать include файла для подключения к БД.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include_once('./db_mysqli.php');
if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT DISTINCT manufacturer FROM      oc_1auto order by 1;")) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $myArray[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($myArray);
} 

$result->close();
```

И ничего не происходит. Данные приходят не в json формате.

Подскажите, куда смотреть?

Comment: разница между 1ым и втором блоке только в include_once. Поэтому закономерный вопрос - что внутри этого include_once ? Второй момент в том что если ошибка вот тут `json_encode`, то вам поможет `json_last_error()`, чтобы узнать что не так внутри и почему не превращает.

Comment: include_once('./db_mysqli.php');
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "main");
 mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");

Comment: а в if вообще заходит ? Я просто почитал про php что include_once перенесет и сразу скомпилит код, но я не был бы так уверен что $connection не бросает ошибку типа " неизвестная переменная - требуется объявление". Ну а другое решение я уже описал выше - смотрите что происходит в json-encode. мб вам приходит пустой ответ или ответ, который не парсится